# Closing material design dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

I have material design dialog:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost CloseOnClickAway="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsOpenDialogAddingEP, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
...
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
<Button Command="{Binding CloseDialogAddingEPCommand}"/>
```

And I ant to close the dialog on clicking the button, In code behinde:

```
public ICommand CloseDialogAddingEPCommand { get; private set; }
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    CloseDialogAddingEPCommand = new RelayCommand(CloseDialogAddingEP);
}
void CloseDialogAddingEP()
{
     IsOpenDialogAddingEP = false;
}
private bool isOpenDialogAddingEP;
public bool IsOpenDialogAddingEP
{
   get { return isOpenDialogAddingEP; }
   set
   {
        isOpenDialogAddingEP = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsOpenDialogAddingEP");
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

but the button doesn't do nothing, can you tell why?

Comment: did you try visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added:

```
public partial class Window:Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

?